# How to make a echo with the title of a jpg but removing the 3 last characters(jpg)?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that shows some products like:
- Title
- Description
- Image

The image when is stored in the table its stores as for example "image.jpg"... But I want to make my images when get uploaded the title of the name of the image will be used to be the title of the html titles of the products (title="echo here"). So for this to be easier I will be using the table of the images and echo in the image tags the name of the image, but I wish to remove the 3 last caracteres that are ".jpg". How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

The function `basename` can do that:

```
$image = 'hello.jpg';
echo basename($image, '.jpg'); // 'hello'
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

Note that this will only work for images with a `.jpg` extension. If you wanted to be more robust and handle, say, `.jpeg` or other file extensions like `.png` etc. you can do the following instead:

```
echo substr($image, 0, strrpos($image, '.'));
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Comment: i did this way, i found in the web, what you think?
<?php 
$image="image.jpg";
echo rtrim($image,'.jpg')
?>

Comment: sure. whatever works, works :) there are so many ways to do what you're looking for. one nice thing about using `basename($image, '.jpg')` is that its main usage adds some useful functionality: if `$image` is a filename with a path, e.g: `/web/path/to/images/hello.jpg`, both the leading path and file extension will be stripped off in one function call, leaving `hello`. that might not be relevant to your use case.. I suppose the real question is, do you need to handle different file extensions? if so, I'd probably go with `substr()` and `strrpos()` for a more bulletproof solution.

Comment: @mauro using `rtrim($image, '.jpg')` is dangerous, because `peep.jpg` will be turned into `pee` :(

Comment: haha! oh yeah... *headslap* totally didn't notice that. yeah, `rtrim` is probably not a good idea then!

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 5.2 you can simply do this, which works for any extension:

```
echo pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Comment: +1 sweet. did not know about that. this is the best answer. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
substr($yourString, 0, -4);
```

And you do the job.

The `substr()` function is used to "cut" some part of string.
In this example, you say that the "cut" starts at position 0 (the beginning of the string) ad ends at the position -4 (three chars of the extension and the dot symbol).

If you're interested in `substr` and his behaviour, please take a look to [that page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 0):

Hi use the explode function to get rid of the extension:

```
$imgParts = explode(".", "image.jpg");
$imageName = $imgParts[0];
```

Comment: A file name may contain more than one period, e.g. picture.1.jpg